# Why this function does not called in Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, frontend, jestjs

I'm trying to **test** a function in **React** using **Jest**. It's working in production and development environments perfectly but Jest is saying it doesn't called.
**As a consequence the state in test returns 0 data length while it should be 1!**

This is the function:

```
  addStory(story) {
const idToken = this.state.user.idToken
if (!idToken) return
const storyProps = {
  Title: story.title,
  Body: story.body,
  UserEntityKey: story.userEntityKey,
  AuthorName: this.state.user.displayName,
  AuthorPicture: this.state.user.photoURL
}

// Axios call should return Promise result for proper testing.
const promise = Axios.post(apiUrl, storyProps, { headers: { 'Authorization': idToken } })
promise.then(res => res.data)
promise.then(newStory => {
  newStory.data.AuthorName = this.state.user.displayName
  newStory.data.AuthorPicture = this.state.user.photoURL
  this.setState(({ data }) => {
    data.unshift(newStory.data)
    return { data: data, isAddStoryVisible: false }
  })
})
promise.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
return promise
```

};

and this is the test:

```js
let story = {
  Title: "title 1",
  body: "body 1",
  UserEntityKey: "userEntityKey",
  Key: "storyKey",
}

test('Story adds based on mocked backend response', async () => {
  MockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve(story)
  )

  const storyApp = shallow(<StoryApp />);

  // Test without idToken
  // Axios call should return Promise result.
  await storyApp.instance().addStory(story)
  expect(storyApp.state().data.length).toEqual(0)

  storyApp.setState((prev) => {
    prev.user = {
      idToken: "asdf",
      displayName: "Test name",
      photoURL: "Test photo"
    }
    return prev
  })

  // Test with idToken
  await storyApp.instance().addStory(story)
  expect(storyApp.state().data.length).toEqual(1)
})
```

and finally here is the test output:

```
  ● Story adds based on mocked backend response

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  1
Received:
  0

  92 |   // Test with idToken
  93 |   await storyApp.instance().addStory(story)
> 94 |   expect(storyApp.state().data.length).toEqual(1)
     |                                        ^
  95 | })
  96 | 
  97 | test('Story deletes based on mocked backend response', async () => {

  at Object.toEqual (__tests__/App.test.js:94:40)
  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
  at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (__tests__/App.test.js:25:103)
  at _next (__tests__/App.test.js:27:194)
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just a typo.

Change how you are mocking `MockAxios.post` to this:

```js
MockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
  Promise.resolve({ data: story })
)
```

...and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian. You saved my time.